# Problema con la librería SDK de Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

¿Por qué se me genera este error?

> Android SDK location should not contain whitespace, as this cause
>   problems with NDK tools

Esto sucede al crear un proyecto ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?

[image: porque se genera este error y que debo hacer para solucionarlo?]

Comment: En lugar de usar la carpeta `Eduar Celeita` usa otra direccion como `C:\proyectos\androidstudio`

Comment: SIMPKEMENTE CREA UNA CARPETA EN C (C:/PROYECTOS) CON UN NOMBRE QUE NO TENGA ESPACIOS LISSTO INSTALAS PAQUETES Y A TRABAJAR :)

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios tuve el mismo problema y lo resolví mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

Justamente el error te dice:

> La ruta del proyecto no debe contener espacios en blanco, ya que esto puede causar problemas con las herramientas de NDK.

Trata de crear tu proyecto en una ruta que no tenga espacios en blanco, por ejemplo crea una carpeta en C:\ProyectosAndroid\

Answer (score 1):

**¡No es problema de la librería!**,

> Android SDK location should not contain whitespace, as this cause
>   problems with NDK tools

esto es un error común tanto **al definir el path del Android SDK como para definir la ruta de los proyectos a crear, no debes tener espacios**, si notas en tu path tienes un espacio:

```
C:\Users\Eduar Celeita\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication
```

Para crear un proyecto debes crear una ruta sin espacio:

```
C:\Users\EduarCeleita\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication
```

o define otro folder donde crear tus proyectos.